# How to display the selected rows of the gridview in another form using C#.Net Form application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How to display the selected rows of the gridview in another form using C#.Net Form application?

Please answer for this with coding. I cant access first form gridview in another form. I want to store the gridview values in another form textboxes.

Comment: welcome to `SO`. Kindly put what you have tried so far? Kindly go through [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Well to start of maybe you can identify the underlying data and make it part of the session and then retrieve it on your subsequent page, but there is just not much information What is the data shown, which fields are you interested in, you should work on making this actually a question.

Answer (score 0):

If its the rows your after, the easiest way to do this would be to have each row be a data bound object. You can do this using any class that contains properties.

```
class Foo
{
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
    public float Column2 { get; set; }
    public int Column3 { get; set; }
}
```

Next, attach a binding list of type Foo to your dataGridView. You may wish to either populate this list yourself or allow the list to be populated by the user using the dataGridView.

```
BindingList<Foo> source = new BindingList<Foo>();

// Add items/rows to list if needed...

dataGridView.DataSource = source;
```

When you want to get the selected rows, just use the SelectedRows property of the dataGridView. Each row contains a DataBoundItem property which holds the data object of the original binding list. An example of how to use this would be to create a new list of selected objects which you could then pass into your second form to be viewed or modified.

```
List<Foo> selected = new List<Foo>();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
    selected.Add(row.DataBoundItem as Foo);

// Assuming your second form has a property for the list to be passed into.

form2.SelectionList = selected;
```